# What is this yellow bulldozer set?

Tags: set-identification, technic

In the research field of neural radiance fields, you frequently find the following yellow LEGO bulldozer, and I assume it a set. (Searching for "neural radiance fields bulldozer" will provide many more images.) Given that many of the parts are the generic 1xn parts with the holes instead of more specialized parts, I assume it is a set from at least ten years ago, if not older.
Can anyone identify what set it is?

[image: yellow lego bulldozer]
<sup>from https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like set # [856: Bulldozer](https://brickset.com/sets/856-1)

[image]

The same set was released in the US with set# [951](https://brickset.com/sets/951-1/Bulldozer)